# getting error Cannot read property 'titles' of null in angular

Tags: angular, typeerror

This is my Card-list-Component.html

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let course of courses" class="course-card mat-elevation-z10">
    <mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-title>{{course.titles.description}}</mat-card-title>

    </mat-card-header>

    <img mat-card-image [src]="course.iconUrl">

    <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{course.titles.longDescription}}</p>
    </mat-card-content>

    <mat-card-actions class="course-actions">

        <button mat-button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.url]">
            VIEW COURSE
        </button>

        <button mat-button class="mat-raised-button mat-accent"
                (click)="editCourse(course)">
            EDIT
        </button>

    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

here is my home-component.html

```
<h3>All Courses</h3>


<mat-tab-group>

    <mat-tab label="Beginners">

        <courses-card-list
                [courses]="[courses$ | async]">

        </courses-card-list>

    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Advanced">

        <courses-card-list
                [courses]="[]"

        ></courses-card-list>

    </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

this is home-component.ts

```
import { Course } from './../model/course';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
 @Component({
     selector: 'home',
     templateUrl: './home.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
 })
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

courses$ : Observable<Course[]>;


  constructor(private db:AngularFirestore) {

}

ngOnInit() {

  this.courses$ = this.db.collection('courses').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(snaps => {
       return snaps.map(snap => {

          return <Course> {
            id: snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...(<Object>snap.payload.doc.data())
          }

      } );

    }));

}}
```

course.ts file

```
export interface Course {
   id:string;
   titles: {
       description:string;
       longDescription: string;
   };
   iconUrl: string;
   uploadedImageUrl:string;
   courseListIcon: string;
   categories:string[];
   lessonsCount:number;
}
```

could anyone please explain why I am getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'titles' of null
at CoursesCardListComponent_mat_card_0_Template (courses-card-list.component.html:7)
at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)
at refreshView (core.js:7198)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8289)
at refreshView (core.js:7222)
at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
at refreshView (core.js:7248)
at refreshComponent (core.js:8335)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6991)
```

i am watching a video tutorial from angular university his code is running prefectly fine
and i am getting this error i dont know why please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Looks like `course.titles.description` is throwing the error as courses is null. log courses and confirm it's not null. Double check you are not doing anything wrong in `ngOnInit()` method

Answer (score 2):

In the template, change all instances of {{course.titles.something}} to {{course?.titles?.something}}

The first time the observable returns data, it might be an invalid/empty array.  If adding the ? removes the error, but the fields still don't have data, you should inspect the course object to make sure that it fits the interface as expected. (double-check case-sensitivity too)

Comment: now the error is gone but no data is displaying inside component,

Comment: there is data in every feild in firbase

Comment: In the Card-list-Component.html, in the mat-card-content, add <div>Course: {{course | json}}</div> and let us know what you get after the Course: in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Man i believe solve that, sorry by late answer, but for future people, the solution to use "?" its parcial correct.
To solve the problem and show the list you need to change ***ngFor="let course of courses"** for ***ngFor="let course of courses[0]"**.
Let's Rock!

Comment: This [0] fixed it for me, i'm currently doing the RxJS Course from Angular School.